# ListView Item clicked Count (Android Java)

Tags: java, android, listview, listviewitem

**Is there a method to count in a ListView how often each Item Clicked ?**

Comment: exists dozens of ways to do that... increasing an int value... with a SharedPreference, with an SQL, with a WebService. You should be more specific with your need and add some codes, any implementation so far or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to create an array of integers that is the same size as the number of items in your listview.

ListView has a method called onItemClick() that tells you which position is clicked.  You can use this method to increment the value at the appropriate index of your array.

Answer (score 0):

There is not. You'll have to keep track of that on your own!

You should keep a counter on the list item's `onClickListener` or `onLongClickListener`

Comment: Where is the difference  ?

Comment: Take a look at the android documentation: 

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html

One gets called when a user long presses, the other on a tap.